# How to include custom Js in AMP website for already built website in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, amp-html

I am implementing AMP in already build website in Laravel. I started with basic steps, I made the following changes in my layout.blade.php (in the head tag):

-- Added this on top:

```
<!doctype html>
```

-- Included amp in html tag.

```
<html amp>
```

-- Included scripts required for AMP.

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>)
```

-- Added meta tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

-- Added link tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ url()->current() }}">
```

-- Added meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
```

-- Added style tag

```
<style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
```

After this, I replaced all image tags with

```
<amp-img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" width="55" height="32"></amp-img>
```

Next error was of CSS, to quick-fix it and to keep my CSS at the current place only, I included it in this way:

```
<style amp-custom="">
    @php include ('css/app.css') @endphp
</style>
```

And in my CSS, I removed all !important attribute, and the error of CSS got fixed.

-- Next error is of js:

```
Custom JavaScript is not allowed. (see https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml#html-tags)
```

I see that there are various methods to include custom JS, but it's not working for me, as my JS code is larger than the size they have specified. The methods which I tried are:

1. Using amp-script tag:

   ```
   <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-MTL2W61Pv6p46ZR8-bKL7vjQ6yWS36CH_bBqhG1eu8DVUD5wVPDCdPiuaCN7mrzW" />
   <amp-script width="200" height="50" script="hello-world">
       <button>Hello amp-script!</button>
   </amp-script>
   <script id="hello-world" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
        @php include ('js/app.js') @endphp
   </script>
   ```

   Via this method, I am having one difficulty that the size of JS inside amp-script tag is predefined, we cannot exceed that. That is why I had to abort this method. Is there any way to change that so that I do not get this error?
2. The next method I tried is with amp-iframe, with that I am able to include all JS in my page, but with that, I am not able to change anything in the parent document

   amp-iframe width=300 height=300 sandbox="allow-scripts" layout="responsive" frameborder="0" src="js_file_path_with_https">

Please let me know what should I do here for fixing this error. Or is there any other way to include my Js?

Note: I have various libraries included in my custom js file: jQuery, Bootstrap, wheelindicator etc.
Thanks

Comment: JS associated with `<amp-script>` has local limits. Total JS per page has page limits. You have to conform to those rules. Also there are some time-limits with which you have to conform. The boilerplate for jQuery and/or Bootstrap will exceed the limits. It's best to eliminate dependencies.

Comment: @jay Right, I understood that to implement AMP I will need to follow all the rules. And I have removed all extra features and dependencies from mobile and its working well now.